# rails6版でgit push heroku masterでデプロイできない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

エラーを読んでみると `bundle lock--add-platform x86_64-linux` と書いてあったのでターミナルで入力して、コミットしてpushして見たところ同じエラーが出ました。

下記のサイトを参考に、Gemfile.lockを再度生成してみましたが変わりませんでした。

[HerokuへPushする際に「Failed to install gems via Bundler.」が出た時の対処法](https://yumishin.com/heroku-push-error/)

こちらのサイトで似たような記事があったので、試してみましたが、変わらず同じエラーが出ています。

分からないまま時間だけが過ぎていく状態です。どうかご教授お願いします。

**実行環境:**

- Ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [x86_64-darwin20]
- Bundler version 2.2.21

---

`heroku logs --tail` の実行結果

```
2021-08-30T12:24:49.448523+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user メールアドレス
2021-08-30T12:24:49.448523+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user メールアドレス
2021-08-30T12:24:49.717428+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user メールアドレス
2021-08-30T12:24:49.717428+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user メールアドレス
2021-08-30T12:24:58.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user メールアドレス
2021-08-30T12:25:02.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/9f407441-7fa5-4b6f-8325-806781542c5f/activity/builds/4365eca8-9fc6-4c89-ae4e-c8fa29e4442d
2021-08-30T12:26:43.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user メールアドレス
2021-08-30T12:26:46.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/9f407441-7fa5-4b6f-8325-806781542c5f/activity/builds/b09ba2f0-6fdc-4050-a741-f9096d8ccd11
2021-08-30T12:27:30.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user メールアドレス
2021-08-30T12:27:33.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/9f407441-7fa5-4b6f-8325-806781542c5f/activity/builds/2a7cc295-e1fb-400e-8125-7b6976ebe39e
2021-08-30T12:34:06.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user メールアドレス
2021-08-30T12:34:10.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/9f407441-7fa5-4b6f-8325-806781542c5f/activity/builds/a2afee68-5c3f-43f0-b3f0-a05cd981c331
2021-08-30T12:43:55.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user メールアドレス
2021-08-30T12:43:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/9f407441-7fa5-4b6f-8325-806781542c5f/activity/builds/9e1e58ea-4eca-4ec5-bdfa-7406e802bbf8
```

`git push heroku master` の実行結果

```
Enumerating objects: 125, done.
Counting objects: 100% (125/125), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (105/105), done.
Writing objects: 100% (125/125), 146.54 KiB | 6.37 MiB/s, done.
Total 125 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote:  !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
remote:             Detected buildpacks: Ruby,Node.js
remote:             See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect-order
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Installing bundler 2.2.21
remote: -----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-3.0.2
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.2.21
remote:        Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
remote:        Your bundle only supports platforms ["x86_64-darwin-20"] but your local platform
remote:        is x86_64-linux. Add the current platform to the lockfile with `bundle lock
remote:        --add-platform x86_64-linux` and try again.
remote:        Bundler Output: Your bundle only supports platforms ["x86_64-darwin-20"] but your local platform
remote:        is x86_64-linux. Add the current platform to the lockfile with `bundle lock
remote:        --add-platform x86_64-linux` and try again.
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 9dfb754c4483d008134222a2332ba8ccf1ffb43c
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 9dfb754c4483d008134222a2332ba8ccf1ffb43c
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to アプリ名
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/アプリ名.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to アプリ名.git
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.0.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4', '>= 6.1.4.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 1.1'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
  # Can be configured to work on production as well see: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/README.md
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.1.4.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.1)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.1.4.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.1)
      activejob (= 6.1.4.1)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4.1)
      activestorage (= 6.1.4.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.1)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.1.4.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.1)
      actionview (= 6.1.4.1)
      activejob (= 6.1.4.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.1.4.1)
      actionview (= 6.1.4.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.1)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.9)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (6.1.4.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.1)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4.1)
      activestorage (= 6.1.4.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.1)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.1.4.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    activejob (6.1.4.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.1.4.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.1)
    activerecord (6.1.4.1)
      activemodel (= 6.1.4.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.1)
    activestorage (6.1.4.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.1)
      activejob (= 6.1.4.1)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.1)
      marcel (~> 1.0.0)
      mini_mime (>= 1.1.0)
    activesupport (6.1.4.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.3)
    addressable (2.8.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.8.1)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.1.3)
    capybara (3.35.3)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    childprocess (3.0.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.9)
    crass (1.0.6)
    erubi (1.10.0)
    ffi (1.15.3)
    globalid (0.5.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.0)
    i18n (1.8.10)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.11.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    listen (3.7.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    loofah (2.12.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (1.0.1)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mini_mime (1.1.1)
    minitest (5.14.4)
    msgpack (1.4.2)
    nio4r (2.5.8)
    nokogiri (1.12.3-x86_64-darwin)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    pg (1.2.3)
    public_suffix (4.0.6)
    puma (5.4.0)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    racc (1.5.2)
    rack (2.2.3)
    rack-mini-profiler (2.3.2)
      rack (>= 1.2.0)
    rack-proxy (0.7.0)
      rack
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (6.1.4.1)
      actioncable (= 6.1.4.1)
      actionmailbox (= 6.1.4.1)
      actionmailer (= 6.1.4.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.1)
      actiontext (= 6.1.4.1)
      actionview (= 6.1.4.1)
      activejob (= 6.1.4.1)
      activemodel (= 6.1.4.1)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4.1)
      activestorage (= 6.1.4.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.1)
      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
      railties (= 6.1.4.1)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.4.2)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (6.1.4.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.1)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.13)
      thor (~> 1.0)
    rake (13.0.6)
    rb-fsevent (0.11.0)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    regexp_parser (2.1.1)
    rubyzip (2.3.2)
    sass-rails (6.0.0)
      sassc-rails (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.1)
    sassc (2.4.0)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc-rails (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
      sassc (>= 2.0)
      sprockets (> 3.0)
      sprockets-rails
      tilt
    selenium-webdriver (3.142.7)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 4.0)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
    semantic_range (3.0.0)
    spring (2.1.1)
    sprockets (4.0.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.2)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.4.2)
    thor (1.1.0)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    turbolinks (5.2.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (2.0.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    web-console (4.1.0)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webdrivers (4.6.1)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
      selenium-webdriver (>= 3.0, < 4.0)
    webpacker (5.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      rack-proxy (>= 0.6.1)
      railties (>= 5.2)
      semantic_range (>= 2.3.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    zeitwerk (2.4.2)

PLATFORMS
  x86_64-darwin-20

DEPENDENCIES
  bootsnap (>= 1.4.4)
  byebug
  capybara (>= 3.26)
  jbuilder (~> 2.7)
  listen (~> 3.3)
  pg (~> 1.1)
  puma (~> 5.0)
  rack-mini-profiler (~> 2.0)
  rails (~> 6.1.4, >= 6.1.4.1)
  sass-rails (>= 6)
  selenium-webdriver
  spring
  sqlite3
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  web-console (>= 4.1.0)
  webdrivers
  webpacker (~> 5.0)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 3.0.2p107

BUNDLED WITH
   2.2.21
```

Comment: `Gemfile.lock` を見る限り正常に追加されていません。 `bundle lock --add-platform x86_64-linux` をもう一度試してください。その後Gemfile.lockのPLATFORMSに `x86_64-linux` が追加されたか確認してください

Comment: sugumuraさんコメントありがとうございます。試して見ましたがまた同じエラーが出ました。

Comment: 問題が解決できました。ブランチ作成してデプロイしていたので、ブランチをmasterに移動してデプロイして見た所デプロイできました。これでやっと進めることができます。sugimuraさんコメントありがとうございました。